# Laravel 5.2 establish web services for mobile app

Tags: web-services, laravel-5

I trying to make a back office using laravel 5.2  for my mobile application.  Where authentication user could be  access of  my  webservice to fetch information.

I had research on that , I also use JWT plugins but its not fit for me. This plugins can't  accept post request.

If you have any idea please share with me.

Comment: Which specific  plugin are you using for JWT?

Comment: I have use "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*".

Comment: I use the same plugin and it does accept post requests. The http verb that you use has nothing to do with the token. What you might be experiencing is an error because of CORS (Cross-Origin HTTP Request).